# Django - display OneToOneField field in other model django admin view

Tags: python, django

I have a OneToOneField between a Vehicle model and a Person model. I would like to view the assigned_person field (using its dropdown functionality) in Person's admin view. The idea is that if I view a Person, I can change the assigned_person value and have it affect Vehicle assigned_person.

[Admin view: Vehicle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wxbp2.png)

[Admin view: Person](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oiruo.png)

models.py:

```
class Vehicle(models.Model):
        ...
        assigned_person = models.OneToOneField('Person', related_name='person', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)                 
       
class Person(models.Model):
       ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try implementing `Tabular inline` in admin.py file instead of registering `Vehicle` directly.

```py
class VehicleInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Vehicle
    extra = 1

class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = (VehicleInline,)

admin.site.register(Person, PersonAdmin)
```

Refer here for more: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#working-with-many-to-many-intermediary-models

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I've already investigated inliens. This functionality doesn't solve my problem. I want to reassign the Vehicle to another Person whilst viewing a record of a Person. I'm not interested in change my Vehicle details.

Answer (score 0):

I would also use inlines to do this, either way, you're asking for some overriding or customization - but I don't like the prospects of having to customize the admin, you will waste a lot of time on it and it's not guaranteed to work.

**Person admin.py**

```
from vehicle.forms import VehicleAssignedPersonForm

class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    change_form = PersonChangeForm
    ...
    inlines = [
        VehicleInline
    ]
    ...

class VehicleInline(admin.TabularInline):
    change_form = VehicleAssignedPersonForm
    model = Vehicle
```

**Person forms.py**

```
class PersonChangeForm(forms.form):
    ...
    //override the save method
    def save():
        //here you will have the ability to call a save for the vehicle's assigned person
```

**Vehicle forms.py**

```
class VehicleAssignedPersonForm(forms.ModelForm):
    assigned_person = forms.ChoiceField()

    //override the __init___ to give the choices that you want to see
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ...

    class Meta:
        model = Vehicle
```

Obviously I have no way of figuring out the details, just pointing you in the direction I would go for this problem.